# Aspose Worksheet not parsing decimal numbers correctly on German server; ignoring period delimiter (123.45 -> 12345)

Tags: server, delimiter, number-formatting, aspose, aspose-cells

I have an import task that parses a huge .dat file as an Aspose Workbook.

This was the original code:

```
    public static List<QueryResult> GetAsposeExcelDocumentWithSheetIndex(string filename, string propertyNames, int sheetIndex = 0, int skipRows = 0, int columnToScanForValidEntries = 0, Stream stream = null)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Begin GetAsposeExcelDocumentWithSheetIndex: Filename: " + filename, typeof(UploadHelper));
        var loadOptions = new Aspose.Cells.LoadOptions(LoadFormat.Excel97To2003);
        if (filename.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
        {
            loadOptions = new Aspose.Cells.LoadOptions(LoadFormat.Xlsx);
        }
        else if (filename.EndsWith(".dat") || filename.EndsWith(".csv"))
        {
            loadOptions = new Aspose.Cells.LoadOptions(LoadFormat.CSV);
        }

        //var fsStats = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/_uploads/ftp/import.txt"), false);
        //fsStats.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + " - Opening file: " + filename);
        //fsStats.Flush();
        loadOptions.ParsingFormulaOnOpen = false;

        try
        {
            var workbook = stream != null ? new Workbook(stream: stream, loadOptions: loadOptions) : new Aspose.Cells.Workbook(filename, loadOptions);

            Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[sheetIndex];

            //fsStats.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + " - Opened sheet");
            //fsStats.Flush();

            var list = new List<QueryResult>();
            for (int i = skipRows, loopTo = worksheet.Cells.Rows.Count + skipRows - 1; i <= loopTo; i++)
            {
                //fsStats.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + " - Reading row: " + i);
                //fsStats.Flush();
                if (worksheet.Cells.GetCell(i, columnToScanForValidEntries) != null &&
                    worksheet.Cells.GetCell(i, columnToScanForValidEntries).Value != null)
                {
                    NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;
                    var obj = new QueryResult();
                    var propNames = propertyNames.Split(',');
                    for (int j = 0, loopTo1 = propNames.Length - 1; j <= loopTo1; j++)
                    {
                        Cell cellInfo = worksheet.Cells.GetCell(i, j);
                        if (cellInfo != null)
                        {
                            // specific excluded properties
                            var propName = propNames[j];

                            var parseAsString = PropNameShouldNeverBeParsedAsDate(propName);                                      

                            if ((cellInfo.Type == CellValueType.IsDateTime) && !parseAsString && cellInfo.DateTimeValue.Year > 2010 && !cellInfo.Name.StartsWith("X") && !cellInfo.Name.StartsWith("Y") && !cellInfo.Name.StartsWith("AC"))  // this second check is bc some dates weren't return as a DateTime type in the Iplot file
                            {
                                // Colmun X and Y should NEVER be a date time
                                obj.Properties.Add(propNames[j], cellInfo.DateTimeValue);
                            }
                            else
                            {                            
                                obj.Properties.Add(propNames[j], cellInfo.StringValue);                             
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            obj.Properties.Add(propNames[j], null);
                        }
                    }

                    list.Add(obj);
                }
            }

            //fsStats.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + " - Done reading");
            //fsStats.Flush();
            //fsStats.Close();
            return list;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.LogError("Error GetAsposeExcelDocumentWithSheetIndex:" + ex.ToString() + ex.StackTrace);

            //fsStats.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + " - Error: " + ex.ToString());
            //fsStats.Flush();
            //fsStats.Close();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This worked as expected on my local, however the production website is hosted in Germany. **The code runs correctly when manually triggered from the admin page (which requires being logged into Sitecore), but when run automatically as a scheduled task, it fails because it's not parsing numbers correctly**

```
public static List<QueryResult> GetAsposeExcelDocumentWithSheetIndex(string filename, string propertyNames, int sheetIndex = 0, int skipRows = 0, int columnToScanForValidEntries = 0, Stream stream = null)
        {
            //var fsStats = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/_uploads/ftp/import.txt"), false);
            //fsStats.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + " - Opening file: " + filename);
            //fsStats.Flush();
            loadOptions.ParsingFormulaOnOpen = false;

            try
            {
                var workbook = stream != null ? new Workbook(stream: stream, loadOptions: loadOptions) : new Aspose.Cells.Workbook(filename, loadOptions);

                Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[sheetIndex];

                //fsStats.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + " - Opened sheet");
                //fsStats.Flush();

                var list = new List<QueryResult>();
                for (int i = skipRows, loopTo = worksheet.Cells.Rows.Count + skipRows - 1; i <= loopTo; i++)
                {
                    //fsStats.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss") + " - Reading row: " + i);
                    //fsStats.Flush();
                    if (worksheet.Cells.GetCell(i, columnToScanForValidEntries) != null &&
                        worksheet.Cells.GetCell(i, columnToScanForValidEntries).Value != null)
                    {
                        NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;
                        var obj = new QueryResult();
                        var propNames = propertyNames.Split(',');
                        for (int j = 0, loopTo1 = propNames.Length - 1; j <= loopTo1; j++)
                        {
                            Cell cellInfo = worksheet.Cells.GetCell(i, j);
                            if (cellInfo != null)
                            {
                                // specific excluded properties
                                var propName = propNames[j];

                                var parseAsString = PropNameShouldNeverBeParsedAsDate(propName);                                      

                                if ((cellInfo.Type == CellValueType.IsDateTime) && !parseAsString && cellInfo.DateTimeValue.Year > 2010 && !cellInfo.Name.StartsWith("X") && !cellInfo.Name.StartsWith("Y") && !cellInfo.Name.StartsWith("AC"))  // this second check is bc some dates weren't return as a DateTime type in the Iplot file
                                {
                                    // Colmun X and Y should NEVER be a date time
                                    obj.Properties.Add(propNames[j], cellInfo.DateTimeValue);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    var value = cellInfo.StringValue;
    
                                    if (cellInfo.Type == CellValueType.IsNumeric || propName.Contains("NUM_VALUE"))
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            if (cellInfo.StringValue == "2.074.927" || cellInfo.DoubleValue == 2074927 || cellInfo.DoubleValue == 2074.927)
                                            {
                                                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Value: " + cellInfo.Value.ToString() + " StringValue: " + cellInfo.StringValue + " DoubleValue: " + cellInfo.DoubleValue.ToString(nfi), typeof(UploadHelper));

                                                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Convert.ToDouble Value: " + Convert.ToDouble(cellInfo.Value) + ", " + Convert.ToDouble(cellInfo.Value).ToString(nfi), typeof(UploadHelper));
                                                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("DoubleValue: " + (cellInfo.DoubleValue) + ", " + (cellInfo.DoubleValue).ToString(nfi), typeof(UploadHelper));
                                                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("StringValue: " + (cellInfo.StringValue), typeof(UploadHelper));

                                                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("FloatValue: " + (cellInfo.FloatValue) + ", " + (cellInfo.FloatValue).ToString(nfi), typeof(UploadHelper));
                                                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("StringValueWithoutFormat: " + (cellInfo.StringValueWithoutFormat), typeof(UploadHelper));
                                                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("IntValue: " + (cellInfo.IntValue), typeof(UploadHelper));

                                            }

                                            if (Convert.ToDouble(cellInfo.Value).ToString() != value)
                                            {
                                                Double val;
                                                if (Double.TryParse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, nfi, out val))
                                                {
                                                    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Using value " + val, typeof(UploadHelper));
                                                    obj.Properties.Add(propNames[j], val);
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Failed to parse as decimal, using stringValue " + value, typeof(UploadHelper));
                                                    obj.Properties.Add(propNames[j], value);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("Value as double matches StringValue", typeof(UploadHelper));
                                                obj.Properties.Add(propNames[j], Convert.ToDouble(cellInfo.Value));
                                            }
                                        }catch(Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info(ex.Message, typeof(UploadHelper));
                                            obj.Properties.Add(propNames[j], cellInfo.StringValue);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        obj.Properties.Add(propNames[j], cellInfo.StringValue);
                                    }                            
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                obj.Properties.Add(propNames[j], null);
                            }
                        }

                        list.Add(obj);
                    }
                }
```

The reason why I added all the additional code for **numeric** values is because on the German server, `cellInfo.StringValue` returns an improperly formatted number as a string - it uses periods instead of commas, so large decimal values end up being returned like `12.703.1005` instead of `12,703.1005`.

So, I tried to return `cellInfo.DoubleValue` instead when the cell is numeric, but that ALSO returns wrong. Some decimals like 12.7 are being interpreted as dates, so `cellInfo.DoubleValue` is entirely wrong, but `cellInfo.StringValue` gives me the correct number (as a string). But the one thing that's still not working either as strings or decimals is large numbers that have a comma and a decimal.

In the second block of code you can see all the logging I added in. Here is the output on my local, for parsing a value of 2074.927

```
27908 10:47:59 INFO  Value: 2074.927 StringValue: 2074.927 DoubleValue: 2074.927
27908 10:48:02 INFO  Convert.ToDouble Value: 2074.927, 2074.927
27908 10:48:04 INFO  DoubleValue: 2074.927, 2074.927
27908 10:48:07 INFO  StringValue: 2074.927
27908 10:48:10 INFO  FloatValue: 2074.927, 2074.927
27908 10:48:21 INFO  StringValueWithoutFormat: 2074.9270000000001
27908 10:48:24 INFO  IntValue: 2074
```

and here is the output on the German server:

```
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  Value: 2074927 StringValue: 2.074.927 DoubleValue: 2074927
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  Convert.ToDouble Value: 2074927, 2074927
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  DoubleValue: 2074927, 2074927
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  StringValue: 2.074.927
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  FloatValue: 2074927, 2074927
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  StringValueWithoutFormat: 2074927
ManagedPoolThread #12 15:36:04 INFO  IntValue: 2074927
```

On the German server, I don't have a single instance of the correct number. It early strips the decimal place (returning the number several orders of magnitude larger than it should be), or it gives me a string value that has a period instead of a comma, which I cannot parse as a decimal.

Why is the German server messing this up? How can I change my code to parse correctly on the German server? As you can see in the code I'm already trying to use `NumberFormatInfo` to give me the correct delimiters but it doesn't matter since the DoubleValue is returning with no delimeter to begin with.

Comment: Answer here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30268/code-on-german-server-parsing-data-correctly-when-run-from-admin-page-but-incor/30269#30269

Comment: I second that. Moreover, you may also try the line (if it makes any difference) using Aspose.Cells APIs:
loadOptions.Region = CountryCode.USA;

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 1):

@Anshul Samaiyar,

If you could specify your custom formatting, i.e., "`## ###.##%`" for the given value to the cell in MS Excel manually, you will also get this result ("`1231123.%`"). So, Aspose.Cells works the same way as MS Excel does. Your custom formatting is not right. Please see the following sample code with (updated) custom formatting and give it a try,  it will give you expected results.

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```java
//Create a new (empty) workbook
Workbook workbook  =  new Workbook();
//Get the first (default) worksheet
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
//Get A1 cell
Cell cell = worksheet.getCells().get("A1");
//Specify double value
Double dataValue = 12311.23;
dataValue = Double.parseDouble(dataValue.toString());
cell.putValue(dataValue);

//Create a style and set the custom formattings
Style cellStyle = workbook.createStyle();
cellStyle.setCustom("## ###.##\\%");
//Apply the style to the cell
cell.setStyle(cellStyle);

//Autofit column to show all values
worksheet.autoFitColumn(0);

//Save the Excel file
workbook.save("f:\\files\\out1.xlsx");
//Save to PDF file
workbook.save("f:\\files\\out12.pdf");
```

Hope this helps, you may also post queries in the dedicated [forums](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

Answer (score 0):

Facing similar issue where

```
dataValue = 12311.23;
dataValue = Double.parseDouble(dataValue.toString());
cellStyle.setCustom("## ###.##%");
```

is not getting change to 12 311.23 but getting g converted to 1231123.% any solution for the issue is welcome.